# Update other table fields based in one line of the same mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, subquery

The image bellow explains what i need to do:

[image: Table with many lines that i need to update]

In other words, i need to update many lines in a table using some data contained in one line (specifically, columns bankId, proj_day and liq_day, printed in red on image above). Note that the column value "id" is the same as the "entryID" column (green mark). The query that i built of course doesn't work. There's more lines like that and i need to update all, based on id joined with entryId.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt!

Comment: can you give the example of result you want, and your query (and the result you get) ?

Comment: my query attempt is on the top of the image.
don't know how but only affects some rows.

Comment: note in query that i duplicate the same database (flux for consulting and flux_exclusive for update) but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with your query and it's working.
I also added some sample data [here](http://rextester.com/KESP67592), you can test it and see.

The only difference that I see in your query is that you don't have a self join (join with the same table). But either way it should work.

```
UPDATE tbl A
INNER JOIN tbl B
    ON A.entryId = B.id
SET A.bankId = B.bankId, A.proj_day = B.proj_day, A.liq_day = B.liq_day
WHERE A.userid = 307 AND A.entryId > 0;
```

Comment: You're right! Shame on me. My query was correct but i'd used two databases (one is a copy of other) for the inner join and i'd saw the results on other database (that not received the update). What a mess... thank you!